# Select Placeholder jade

Tags: javascript, select, pug

This is the code I currently have. I need to add a placeholder that doesn't give a value.

```
     select.edit-profile-name(type="text", data-featurename="Options", class="attrs-feature-input")
        - each val in Mi.CMS.performer.attributes.options
          option
            =val
```

I assumed this was the code I would need but, but while this does display "Select One" by default I then get my options with "select one" listed over and over again on top of my options.

```
          select.edit-profile-name(type="text", data-featurename="Options", class="attrs-feature-input")
            - each val in Mi.CMS.performer.attributes.options
              option(value='', selected='selected') Select One
              option
                =val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pull your default option out of the loop.

```
select
  option(value='', selected='selected') Select One
  each val in theList
      option= val
```